# Percentile of a discrete distribution with degenerate scores

Tags: statistics, descriptive-statistics, percentile

I have a ranked dataset of 100 entries, where 10 entries have score 1 and 90 have score 0. How to interpret the first percentile of this dataset? Does this consist of the 10 entries with score 1? If no, than is there a standard term for the subset of this 10 entries?

Comment: The first percentile is clearly $0$ (you start at the bottom of the ranked data).  A harder question is the $90$th percentile as $90\%$ of the data is $0$ or less and $10\%$ of the data is $1$ or more. (A related question is whether there should be $99$ or $101$ percentiles as boundaries or $100$ percentiles as intervals.)